pyinstaller ModuleNotFoundError: 'fake_useragent.data'
above all, thanks for coming.
I'm doing web-scrapping and making it into .exe file
codes works well but not in .exe file
what I want : working exe file, avoid bot detection
what I'm doing :
I'm making web-scrapping.
because of the bot detection, I'm using fake_useragent
from ipypb import ipb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
# from user_agent import generate_user_agent

import requests
import urllib.parse
import time
import random




def download(dir_to_save, url_to_download) :


    # Instantiate the UserAgent class
    ua = UserAgent()
    
    # Get random user agents
    random_ua = ua.random
    
    
    headers = {
    
    'user-agent': random_ua
    # "User-Agent": generate_user_agent(os='win',device_type='desktop')
    # "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

    }


without the fake_useragent .exe file also works but getting into bot-detection, guessing with the slow speed
and this is the error message
Unable to find local data/json file or could not parse the contents using importlib-resources. Try pkg-resource next.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fake_useragent\utils.py", line 21, in load
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 22, in files
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 53, in get_package
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 44, in resolve
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fake_useragent.data'
Could not find local data/json file or could not parse the contents using pkg-resource.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fake_useragent\utils.py", line 21, in load
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 22, in files
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 53, in get_package
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 44, in resolve
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fake_useragent.data'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fake_useragent\utils.py", line 36, in load
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\sa031\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI180322\\fake_useragent\\data\\browsers.json'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
  File "download.py", line 81, in <lambda>
  File "main_final.py", line 18, in download
  File "fake_useragent\fake.py", line 76, in __init__
  File "fake_useragent\utils.py", line 52, in load
fake_useragent.errors.FakeUserAgentError: ('Data list is empty', None)


I tried
1.google it
2. try to find the hints in stackoverflow
3. using pyinstaller with --onefile option in command
4. going on official page.
the closest question was in here
pyinstaller module not found fake_useragent
but the solution in the answer was not supported anymore.
It will be so nice if somebody gives me advice.
It's almost there to reach out for my first actual program.
thanks for reading.

Actually, the link you posted in the past received a new answer in Aug 2024. This one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78876788/9151070
The suggestion is to use --collect-datas=fake_useragent in the pyinstaller. I was facing the same issue as you and this suggestion fixed it. Example:
pyinstaller --collect-datas=fake_useragent --onefile -w my_project.py

